# Remove or delete existing free Application and publish again as paid with same package name

Tags: android, google-play

If I published a free Application in Google play,then how to make this Application as paid Application or add In-App purchase feature?

I read in developer document,

> Once you publish your app as a free app, you cannot ever change it to
>   being a priced app. However, you can still sell in-app products and
>   subscriptions through Google Play's In-app Billing service.
>           If you publish your app as a priced app, you can change it at any time to being a free app (but cannot then change it back to
>   priced). You can also sell in-app products and subscriptions.

1. Can I remove or delete existing free Application and publish again as paid with same package name?
2. Can I add In-App purchase option for existing free Application with update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I remove or delete existing free Application and publish again as paid with same package name?

No. Once an app has been published with a package name, that particular package name is forever considered used by Google, whether or not the app is in a published or unpublished state.

> Can I add In-App purchase option for existing free Application with update?

Yes. The process is the same one that's described [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) for all apps, paid or free.

Comment: @EmilAdz It doesn't call for much more :P